# How to handle file being uploaded by C# httpWebRequest Stream using Perl CGI script on the server side?

Tags: c#, perl, apache, cgi

I am trying to write a Perl CGI script that will save the file, uploaded by client machine, to a file on server. On the client side a C# code uses httpWebRequest and sends data over a stream.

The upload data seemed to have no parameter associated with it so I had hard time reading it (I have no knowledge of C#). After searching here at Stackoverflow I managed to capture the data using,

```
$query = CGI->new();
$data = $query->param('POSTDATA');
```

i could now directly write this data to a file,

```
open ( FH, ">$filename" ) or die ("error opening file $filename: $!");
print FH $data;
close FH;
```

This works fine for small sized files. But when POSTDATA contains large data, sized more than 500MB, the Perl CGI script waits till all of the file is downloaded and then writes it to a file. It seems POSTDATA contains the whole file. This causes stress over system memory. Is there any other way to read the httpWebrequest stream data and write it to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with the [CGI](http://p3rl.org/CGI) module. Also, I am not aware of any Perl CGI implementation that gives you a streaming handle for POST data.

Consider switching to PSGI. The [`body` method in Plack::Request](http://p3rl.org/Plack%3a%3aRequest#body-input) gives you a file handle to read from.

---

Example app (untested):

```
plackup -MIO::File::WithPath -MPlack::Request -MSys::Sendfile=sendfile -e '
    my $app = sub {
        my ($env) = @_;
        my $out = IO::File::WithPath->new("/tmp/out", "w") or die $!;
        my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
        my $r = sendfile($out, $req->body) or die $!;
        return [200, [], []]
    }
'
```

---

```
lwp-request -m POST -c text/plain -USe http://localhost:5000 < /usr/src/linux/COPYING
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I'll try it out as soon as possible.